# Is this modified H. Friedman theory bi-interpretable with ZFC + ORD is Mahlo?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

The following  theory is a modification of Harvey Friedman [$\sf K(W)$](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/TalkAxiomSetThy-ts05xn.pdf) theory.

**Language:** first order logic with equality, membership, and a constant symbol $W$.

**Axioms:**

**Extensionality:** $\forall z \, (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$

**Subworld Replacement:** if $\varphi(x,y,a,\vec{p})$ is a formula that doesn't use "$b$", having all of its free variables among "$x,y,a,\vec{p}$"; then: $$ \forall x \in a \exists z \forall y \, [ \varphi(x,y,a,\vec{p}) \to y=z \land (z \in a \lor z \in W)] \\\land  a \in W \\ \to \exists b \in W : b=\{y\mid \exists x \in a \, \varphi(x,y,a,\vec{p})\}$$

**Reducibility:** if $\phi$ is a formula in ${\sf FOL} (=,\in)$, with all its free variables among "$x,\vec{p}$ "; then: $$\vec{p} \in W \land \exists x ( \phi) \to \exists x \in W(\phi)$$

**Foundation:** as in $\sf ZFC$.

**Choice:** as in $\sf ZFC$.

/

This blows up its strength to $\sf ORD \ is \ Mahlo$.  (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/317663/95347) for a proof of that result in a related [theory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/317658/95347), where I don't see the extra-class features related to that theory being used in the proof of that result)

> Is this theory bi-interpretable with $\sf ZFC + ORD \ is \ Mahlo$? The latter is the scheme:
> $$\forall  \alpha \exists \beta>\alpha\; \varphi(\beta)\land \\\forall \alpha(\forall \beta<\alpha\exists \gamma\in[\beta,\alpha)\; \varphi(\gamma)\to \varphi(\alpha))\\\to \\\exists \kappa(\varphi(\kappa)\land \kappa \text { is strongly inaccessible}).$$
> Where $\alpha $ range over ordinals.